# AWK merge files questions

Tags: awk

I would like to merge 2 files and produce output file as below:

```
input1.txt
113812627 <prepaid@xxx.com>
113812628 <user@yyy.com>
113812629 <hello@zzz.com>

input2.txt
113812627 <user1@xxx.com>
113812628 <user1@yyy.com>
113812627 <user2@xxx.com>
113812628 <user2@yyy.com>
113812629 <user1@zzz.com>
113812629 <user2@zzz.com>

output.txt
113812627 <prepaid@xxx.com> <user1@xxx.com> <user2@xxx.com>
113812628 <user@yyy.com> <user1@yyy.com> <user2@yyy.com>
113812629 <hello@zzz.com> <user1@zzz.com> <user2@zzz.com>
```

How can I use awk command to do this ?

Thanks in advance
Mike

Comment: `awk '{a[$1]=a[$1] OFS $2}END{for(i in a) print i a[i]}' file1 fle2 file3 flle4 ...`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Thanks a lot for your questions. It would be nice if you could show us what you tried so far. This way, we can see in which direction you are searching to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `input1.txt` content be

```
113812627 <prepaid@xxx.com>
113812628 <user@yyy.com>
113812629 <hello@zzz.com>
```

and `input2.txt` content be

```
113812627 <user1@xxx.com>
113812628 <user1@yyy.com>
113812627 <user2@xxx.com>
113812628 <user2@yyy.com>
113812629 <user1@zzz.com>
113812629 <user2@zzz.com>
```

then

```
awk '{arr[$1] = arr[$1] " " $2}END{for(i in arr){printf "%s%s\n",i,arr[i]}}' input1.txt input2.txt
```

gives output

```
113812627 <prepaid@xxx.com> <user1@xxx.com> <user2@xxx.com>
113812628 <user@yyy.com> <user1@yyy.com> <user2@yyy.com>
113812629 <hello@zzz.com> <user1@zzz.com> <user2@zzz.com>
```

Explanation: for each line I append to value under key shown in 1st filed (`$1`) space and 2nd field (`$2`), if it was not yet present, space followed by content of 2nd field is place. After all lines are processed for each key in array I `printf` that key and value under that key, note that space is not required in 1st argument as it is already 1st character of each value.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*